# Realm delete object

Tags: android, gridview, realm

i have some names of cities in grid view, on click of any item i remove that name from realm.
but after delete i update the adapter using notifyDataSetChanged and then last object of gridview replace the position from where i deleted name.
i want to push all name one step up from where i am deleting the name. e.g i have deleted name at position 2 then name of position 3 move on position 2 and so on.
hope you understand the question sorry for bad English
any suggestion and help appreciated.
thanks

Comment: are you using RealmBaseAdapater for your adapter?

Comment: No, i am using CutomAdapter extends BaseAdapter

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior. Internally Realm does a move-last-over kind of deletion, which is much faster than having to shift all the items after the deleted one.

The way to solve this is to use sorting. For example you could store an insertion timestamp in your model and sort the query result using that.